# Curvature Simple Question

Tags: calculus

I just recently learnt curvature by myself, and I encounter a question.
Capture the curvature of r(t) =  when t =1.

I know the basic K = the absolute value of derivative T(tangent vector) divide the absolute value of derivative of r(t)

but it does not provide tangent vector here, any suggestion?

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax guide. You may also have some incomplete equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should do first is understanding $$\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{T}} = \overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{r'}}/|\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{r'}}|$$

This will tell you how to get a tangent vector. 
However, there is the other equation that can help you solve this question. 
You can use the other equation:
$$K = |\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{r'}}*\overrightarrow{\boldsymbol{r''}}|$$
You can find the dot products between these two vectors to solve this.